# What can I see my backgroundColor from UIView

Tags: xcode, uiview, uiimageview

For the entire question : What can I see my backgroundColor from my UIView, because the UIView it's behind my UIImageView.

And I don't know the exact properties for achieve this.

[image]

On this screenshot you can see `view Moved` it's my UIView, inside of this I have an UIImageView called `LogoIV`

I apply a BackgroundColor on `ViewMoved` But now I have an UIImageView and the BackgroundColor properties can't visible because I have the UIImageView in the front.

And I would like to achieve like that : http://www.giphy.com/gifs/2xPJ7BpLYoxO0zI9oF

When I go to the right or to left I have a green or red background

Comment: Sorry. Couldn't understand your question. Can you show us with an example code and screenshot maybe?

Comment: Yes, sorry, please a moment for updating my question

Comment: @RakeshaShastri I've updated my answer I hope you understand :)

Comment: How does the resulting screen look like? and what are you trying to make it look like?

Comment: I updated the initial post @RakeshaShastri

Comment: @KolaCaine Going by your explaination, I understand that you have a UIImageView over the UIView and thats kind of adding a mask. Try changing the background color of UIImageView to clearColor/ make it transparent. That should solve the problem